# Cannot import Python hdfs client or config modules from hdfscli

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to create a Python 3 HDFS client using the hdfscli library.  Per the documentation, I've tried

```
import hdfs

client = hdfs.config.Config().get_client("dev")
```

which yields `AttributeError: module 'hdfs' has no attribute 'config'`

and I've tried

```
import hdfs

client = hdfs.client.InsecureClient("http://<target/IP/address/>")
```

which yields `AttributeError: module 'hdfs' has no attribute 'client'`.

I've also tried `from hdfs import client` and `from hdfs import config`, which yield `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'` and `ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'hdfs'` respectively.

I'm using poetry for package management, and I've re-run `poetry lock` and `poetry install` to no avail.  The `pyproject.toml` file lists `hdfs = "^1.0.1"`.  I have a hdfscli.cfg file a couple levels up from the script that's trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `poetry remove hdfs`, `poetry add hdfs`, `poetry lock`, and `poetry install` again seems to have resolved the issue.  The `pyproject.toml` file now lists `hdfs = "^2.7.0"` so I may have just had quite an old hdfs version.